# Hibernate Field annotation joinColumn set id and get object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Is there anyway to **set id and get project object** for the below **project** field using **filed annotation**. so that i can set only **project id** while persisting in this child table **instead of setting the whole object** while persisting since we are going to save only id of project in board_project table. My be a duplicate i couldn't find other links. This is like **we are in practice of using filed annotation instead of method**.

Using : hibernate5.0 - jpa2.1 lombok(i.e getter/setter) for Spring-data-commons-1.13 for CRUD Operations

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "board_project")
public class BoardProject {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "board_project_id_generator", sequenceName = "board_project_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "board_project_id_generator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "board_id")
    private Long boardId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;          // field set id and get object
   }
```

Project Entity :

```
public class Project{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "project_id_generator", sequenceName = "project_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "project_id_generator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Update: Found something like this

> ```
> @ManyToOne
> @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
> private Project project;
>
> @Column(name = "project_id")
> @NotNull
> private Long projectId;
> ```

Don't know is it ok

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: in your `Project` class mark every field you don't want to persist in database with `@Transient`

Comment: Project is another entity if i put @Transient i cant persist data for project

Comment: i've reread the question i think you want to have the `BoardProject` table which only contains the ID of the related `Project`. this is done right already. but you did not clearly state what else should happen. for example what exactly you want to have persisted in your `Project` table

Comment: Why don't you post the `Project` entity and the code where you're trying to save the `BoardProject` entity if you need help? Look, I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve or where you're facing a difficulty.

Comment: Borad and Project are separate entity where i will persist them separately their relation table is BoardProject where i want to persist id of project and board alone  like above entity but while getting i want to get project as jointcolumn. Project has its own filed like name, description etc..

Comment: `Update: Found something like this `: in which entity did you find them? If I understood you: you have two entities `Project` and `Board` that are having a many-to-many relationship where `board_project` is the table containing the IDs of both entities. If that is the case, you don't need the `BoardProject` entity.  You should use `@ManyToMany` annotation on both entities, and the relationship table will be created for you automatically. If you don't know how to do it, just leave me a comment.